# why are element overflowing when overflow is hidden on root element?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have a root div
with following css:

```
height: 100vh;
overflow: hidden;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
padding: 2.5rem;
background: red;
```

then a child div:

```
flex: 1;
background: blue;
```

here is the full code snippet that uses tailwindCSS:

```
<div className="bg-red-200 h-full flex flex-col p-10 overflow-hidden">
    <div className="bg-blue-200 flex-1">
</div></div>
```

we get the result:
[first-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBEWM.png)

now when i add a p tag with a font-size set to 30px;

the text overflows outside of the inner div as seen here: [second-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8Jvf.png)

Since the text is overflowing into the parent div ( which has overflow set to hidden ) why is the overflowed text still shown?

I understand that if I set overflow-hidden on the paragraph tag itself or its direct parent the text becomes hidden.

but I want to understand why setting overflow hidden on the root element doesn't prevent this?

Comment: overflow isn't inherited.

Answer (score 0):

```
.text-truncate {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```